# Haskell Polymorphism With Kinds and Type Variables

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

In Haskell I have learnt that there are *type variables* (ex. `id :: a -> a`), applied to type signatures, and *kinds* (ex. `Maybe :: * -> *`), applied to type constructors and type classes. A type must have kind `*` (be a concrete type) in order to hold values.

We use type variables to enable polymorphism: `Nothing :: Maybe a` means that the constant `Nothing` can belong to a family of possible types. This leads me to believe that kinding and type variables serve the same purpose; wouldn't the last code sample work as simply `Nothing :: Maybe`, where type class Maybe remains with the kind `* -> *` to signify that the type belongs to generic family?

What it seems we are doing is taking an empty parameter (`* -> *`) and filling it  in with a type variable (`a`) that represents the same level of variance.

We see this behavior in another example:

```
>>> :k Either
Either :: * -> * -> *
>>> :t Left ()
Left () :: Either () b
>>> :t Right ()
Right () :: Either a ()
```

Why is it theoretically necessary to make the distinction between kinds and type variables?

Comment: [It's not](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/planned-change-to-ghc-merging-types-and-kinds/)

Comment: @bheklilr I think OP has something different in mind, although I don't quite get it.

Comment: If you enable `PartialTypeSignatures`, you can put `_` instead of type variables. For example, `Nothing :: Maybe _` or `Left () :: Either _ _`. What you propose would be a simple syntactic extension, but I'm not sure it wouldn't introduce more confusion (especially in the context of other extensions like `PolyKinds`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are distinct just like typing and usual (value-level) variables are distinct. Variables *have* types, but they *aren't* types. So also, type variables *have* kinds. Type variables are the primary notion: without them you don't have parametric polymorphism, and they exist also in many other languages like Java, C#, etc. But Haskell goes further in allowing types-which-take-parameters (`[]`, `Maybe`, `->`, etc.) to exist on their own and to have type variables which represent such non-concrete types. And this means it needs a kind system to disallow things like `Maybe Int Int`.

From the example, it seems that you suggest that you can write a signature without type variables and restore it to the signature with them. But then how could you distinguish `a -> b -> a` and `a -> b -> b`?

Comment: It's fine to mash types and kinds together.  In fact, the latest ghc has a language extension for that.  Though, viewed as a logic type-in-type has to be handled very carefully to avoid inconsistencies.  But that doesn't matter for Haskell.